# when trying to access pages or blocks i get Attention something went wrong

Tags: magento2

When I am trying to access pages or blocks I get Attention something went wrong and looked at all other options that may be related or close to this issue but none will resolve my problem

I can access widgets, here is no error log to view either.

I have a option to add a new page or block but when I save it, same issue Attention something happens.

Also now if I go to Stores Configuration I can not access web design etc they are not there only 
GENERAL
CATALOG
CUSTOMERS
SALES
SERVICES
ADVANCED

but now expand when clicked on?

Suggestions please as my backup has the same issue.

Comment: Please check on `var\log`

Answer (score 0):

Ok Rule no one Back track all the steps you make before a issue arises !!!

I had the day before played with making a new theme and even though i had not selected it the new theme screwed up things..

Removed new folders for the theme and all is back as should be

Fool me !!! lol  but hope this may help some one else